# Randomly select k numeric elements from a sparse matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a sparse matrix (57% sparsity) and would like to randomly select k numeric values from the matrix to be able to split my data into a training and test data set.

I have created a reproducible data set:

```
movies = c("HP1", "HP2", "HP3", "TW", "SW1", "SW2", "SW3")
users = c("A", "B", "C", "D")

row1 = c(4, NA, NA, 5, 1, NA, NA)
row2 = c(5, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA)
row3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 4, 5, NA)
row4 = c(NA, 3, NA, NA, 1, NA, 3)

ratings_matrix = rbind(row1, row2, row3, row4)
ratings_matrix = as.matrix(ratings_matrix)

colnames(ratings_matrix) = movies
rownames(ratings_matrix) = users
```

Assuming there is some random sampling that can be built in, I would like to get an output that looks something as follows:

Training matrix:

```
  HP1 HP2 HP3 TW SW1 SW2 SW3
A   4  NA  NA  5  NA  NA  NA
B   5   5  NA NA  NA  NA  NA
C  NA  NA  NA  2   4  NA  NA
D  NA  NA  NA NA   1  NA   3
```

Test matrix:

```
  HP2 HP3 SW1 SW2
A  NA  NA  1   NA
B  NA   4  NA  NA
C  NA  NA  NA   5 
D  3   NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I have randomly partitioned data sets into training and test sets based on the number of rows, so that the training set gets 75% of the data and the test set gets 25% of the data, for example.

Here is the code for that, where all I ever change is the first two lines for how much of the data set (called `dat` here but would be `ratings_matrix` as in your question) I want to give to the training set and to the test set:

```
## Set the fractions of the dataframe to split into training and test.
training.size   <- 0.75
test.size       <- 0.25

## Compute sample sizes based on proportion of data I want for each data set. 
training.N   <- floor(training.size   * nrow(dat)) 
test.N       <- floor(test.size       * nrow(dat))

# Create the randomly-sampled indices for the dataframe. Use setdiff() to avoid overlapping subsets of indices.
#For example, training.indices explained: randomly sample the dataset for all columns, choose 75% of the total values, and do not sample with replacement. Assign those new values to a new data.frame, training.indices.

set.seed(4444) #Because the sorting is random, setting the seed ensures reproducibility for future analyses

training.indices    <- sort(sample(seq_len(nrow(dat)), size=training.N, replace=FALSE))
NOTtraining.indices <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(dat)), training.indices)

# Assign the dataframes for training and test.
training.data   <- dat[training.indices, ]
test.data       <- dat[NOTtraining.indices, ]
```

So, you can use this for matrices or convert your matrix into a dataframe.

Further, your question indicates you want to partition your data set so that the test set has only a subset of the overall columns. I have never seen that, and I am not sure that is what folks mean when they partition data sets into training and test sets.

However, if that really is your intent, then everywhere the code above says `nrow`, just substitute it with `ncol`, and everywhere you see `ncol`, just substitute it with `nrow`.
Also, change the last two lines to:

```
training.data   <- dat[ ,training.indices]
test.data       <- dat[ ,NOTtraining.indices]
```

That will get you to your desired output, as in the question.

Comment: (1) In addition to changing `nrow` to `ncol`, you'll need to change the comma-indexing in the last two lines of your code. (2) This can and will produce train/test pairs that are not 75%/25% as desired, and this is not really avoidable. It might be necessary to loop and/or somehow add constraints so that something closer than 10 and 2 (83%/17%) can be assured (if not truly guaranteed). (3) Agree completely on questioning the subsetting of columns ... seems odd to me, must be something else we don't know about the data. (Perhaps it should be in long-format instead of this wide-format?)

Comment: Apologies for not giving further information to clarify. I am trying to build a recommender system and wanted to follow the train / test split approach from https://www.ethanrosenthal.com/2015/11/02/intro-to-collaborative-filtering/

Comment: How could we edit this code such that there is at least one entry in both the training and test matrix. If I sample the columns in this way, I get the case where the training matrix might not have any reviews from a particular user.

Answer (score 1):

You can randomly sample the columns by taking an array from 1 to the column size, then randomly sampling from that array using `sample(array, number_to_sample)`

```
# select number of columns
ncol <- dim(ratings_matrix)[2]

# percentage of training/testing split, change this percentage
# as needed, then round to integer
split <- round(0.5 * ncol)

# random sample
set.seed(100) # seed for consistency
rsample <- sample(1:ncol, split)

# training
ratings_matrix[,rsample]

# testing, select values not used in training
ratings_matrix[,-rsample]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and the example website you provided (https://www.ethanrosenthal.com/2015/11/02/intro-to-collaborative-filtering/), I am creating an entirely different answer, because my original answer still addresses your original question.

Here is my answer to your modified question in the comments:

Create the example data objects.
*Note:* the example website has separated the movie name and the rating into different columns, which is tidier data. Your example data do not separate the movie name and rating, so if you wanted to partition the movie ratings just like the website you provided, you would have to group by user AND movie name.

```
movies = c("HP1", "HP2", "HP3", "TW", "SW1", "SW2", "SW3")
users = c("A", "B", "C", "D") 
row1 = c(4, NA, NA, 5, 1, NA, NA)
row2 = c(5, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA)
row3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 4, 5, NA)
row4 = c(NA, 3, NA, NA, 1, NA, 3)

ratings_df <- as.data.frame(rbind(row1, row2, row3, row4))
colnames(ratings_df) <- movies 
ratings_df <- cbind(ratings_df, users) #users cannot be rownames, because they are not unique values, so I created a column for users, which is similar to the example website you provided

ratings_df
     HP1 HP2 HP3 TW SW1 SW2 SW3 users
row1   4  NA  NA  5   1  NA  NA     A
row2   5   5   4 NA  NA  NA  NA     B
row3  NA  NA  NA  2   4   5  NA     C
row4  NA   3  NA NA   1  NA   3     D
```

The for loop performs the random sampling for each user (group), one at a time. For you to use this practically, you would just change the 0.80 value (to sample 80% of the original data set, `ratings_df`) into whatever proportion you want in the original empty test.matrix and in the creation of object `S`. Basically, anywhere you see 0.80 in the code, change it to whatever size of test data you want.

```
N <- nrow(ratings_df)                  #number of rows in overall ratings_df
users <- unique(ratings_df[ ,"users"]) #names in users column
k <- length(users)                     #number of users
p <- ncol(ratings_df) -1               #number of movies, do not include users column
test.matrix <- cbind(matrix(0, nrow= k, ncol = as.integer(0.80*p)), users) #generate an empty matrix with users as the last column

for (i in 1:k) {
   idx = ratings_df$users %in% users[i];  #find rows for this user and return logical
   X   = ratings_df[idx, ];               #extract actual row values for i_th user
   X.red = subset(X, select = c(-users)); #X.red = remove users column so sample function doesn't include users column as part of sample
   set.seed(4444)                         #Because the sorting is random, setting the seed ensures reproducibility for future analyses
   S = X.red[ ,sample(ncol(X.red), size=as.integer(0.80*p))];
  #randomly sample the movie columns in each user group without replacement, by returning a proportion of movies per user
   S.users = as.matrix(cbind(S, users=users[i])); #add users column to S
   test.matrix[i,] <- S.users                #append S.users into existing test.matrix by-rows
   colnames(test.matrix) <- colnames(S.users) #keep column names from S.users for final test.matrix column names
}
```

Your output is `test.matrix`:

```
      test.matrix
             TW  SW2 HP2 HP1 SW1 users
        [1,] 5   NA   NA   4   1   A  
        [2,] NA  NA   5    5   NA  B  
        [3,] 2   5    NA   NA  4   C  
        [4,] NA  NA   3    NA  1   D
```

This output, `test.matrix` matches the structure from your example, and I just arbitrarily chose 80%.